# JSF Stack exception or managed bean trouble

Tags: xml, jsf, managed-bean

I am very new to JSF and have been trying to get this to work for the last hour or so.

This example program I am working on is supposed to display a webpage with several different forms on it. It does that fine (as in it at least works I really do not know how correct the syntax is) and now I implemented some functionality to the form using a managed bean. The goal is to have the page display what the user typed in below to show that it went through, but it seems that there is some sort of ****config.xml problem that I cannot figure out because the project I created in netbeans does not have any sort of config.xml file, it only has a beans.xml file and a web.xml file. I am unsure what (if anything) I need to add to the beans.xml file or if I need to create a new xml file myself or it is something completely different.

I should also mention that when I run this program, the GUI part runs and I can input stuff into the boxes and check the radio boxes and such but when I hit the "Register" button, nothing happens

Here are my files.

index.xhtml

```
       <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <h:head>
    <title>Student Registration Form</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <!-- Use h:graphicImage -->
      <h3>Student Registration Form
        <h:graphicImage name="usIcon.gif" library="image"/>
      </h3>

      <!-- Use h:panelGrid -->
      <h:panelGrid columns="6" style="color:green">
        <h:outputLabel value="Last Name"/>
        <h:inputText id="lastNameInputText" 
                     value="#{Registration.lastName}"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="First Name" />
        <h:inputText id="firstNameInputText" 
                     value="#{Registration.firstName}"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="MI" />
        <h:inputText id="miInputText" size="1"
                     value="#{Registration.mi}"/>
      </h:panelGrid>

      <!-- Use radio buttons -->
      <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel>Gender  </h:outputLabel>           
        <h:selectOneRadio id="genderSelectOneRadio"
                          value="#{Registration.gender}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Male" 
                        itemLabel="Male"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Female" 
                        itemLabel="Female"/>
        </h:selectOneRadio>
      </h:panelGrid>

      <!-- Use combo box and list -->
      <h:panelGrid columns="4">
        <h:outputLabel value="Major  "/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="majorSelectOneMenu"
                         value="#{Registration.major}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Computer Science"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Mathematics"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu> 
        <h:outputLabel value="Minor  "/>
        <h:selectManyListbox id="minorSelectManyListbox"
                             value="#{Registration.minor}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Computer Science"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Mathematics"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="English"/>
        </h:selectManyListbox> 
      </h:panelGrid>

      <!-- Use check boxes -->
      <h:panelGrid columns="4">
        <h:outputLabel value="Hobby: "/>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox id="hobbySelectManyCheckbox"
                              value="#{Registration.hobby}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Tennis"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Golf"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Ping Pong"/>
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
      </h:panelGrid>

      <!-- Use text area -->
      <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputLabel>Remarks:</h:outputLabel>  
        <h:inputTextarea id="remarksInputTextarea" 
                         style="width:400px; height:50px;" 
                         value="#{Registration.remarks}"/>
      </h:panelGrid>

      <!-- Use command button -->
      <h:commandButton value="Register" />
      <br />
      <h:outputText escape="false" style="color:red"
                    value="#{Registration.response}" />
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Registration.java

```
    package jsf2demo;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped

public class Registration {
  private String lastName;
  private String firstName;
  private String mi;
  private String gender;
  private String major;
  private String[] minor;
  private String[] hobby;
  private String remarks;

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getMi() {
    return mi;
  }

  public void setMi(String mi) {
    this.mi = mi;
  }

  public String getGender() {
    return gender;
  }

  public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  public String getMajor() {
    return major;
  }

  public void setMajor(String major) {
    this.major = major;
  }

  public String[] getMinor() {
    return minor;
  }

  public void setMinor(String[] minor) {
    this.minor = minor;
  }

  public String[] getHobby() {
    return hobby;
  }

  public void setHobby(String[] hobby) {
    this.hobby = hobby;
  }

  public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
  }

  public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    this.remarks = remarks;
  }

  public String getResponse() {
    if (lastName == null)
      return ""; // Request has not been made
    else {
      String allMinor = "";
      for (String s: minor) {
        allMinor += s + " ";
      }

      String allHobby = "";
      for (String s: hobby) {
        allHobby += s + " ";
      }

      return "<p style=\"color:red\">You entered <br />" + 
         "Last Name: " + lastName + "<br />" + 
         "First Name: " + firstName + "<br />" + 
         "MI: " + mi + "<br />" +
         "Gender: " + gender + "<br />" + 
         "Major: " + major + "<br />" + 
         "Minor: " + allMinor + "<br />" + 
         "Hobby: " + allHobby + "<br />" + 
         "Remarks: " + remarks + "</p>"; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your button has neither an action nor an actionListener.  I think you'll have to bind a method to run when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 3):

One of the goals of the JSF framework is to support "MVC" architecture, that's why, it provides so many fonctionalities and technologies to elaborate the MVC principles. That's why it's not strongly recommanded to mix the view with the controller tiers, so you should separate between these two tiers, because each tier has its ows special role.
First, you shouldn't add/modify any other xml files if you're using JSF 2.X version.
To illustrate the registration process in your example, you can for example show the registration filled informations in a second simple page named `result.xhtml`. First replace the method `getResponse()` by just `response()` with the content:

```
public String response(){
    return "result?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The outcome string provided through the method above can be written simply `return "result";` then, the URI adress in the browser bar will not be changed while forwarding to the destination page. Else, if the string (page's name) is followed by `faces-redirect=true` like the example, then the URI adress will be changed, and the destination's name will be displayed as well in the browser adress bar.

**See also** :
Difference between forwarding and redirecting in JSF : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-page-forward-vs-page-redirect/

Then, in `index.xhtml`, you made the `<h:commandButton />` without `action` necessary attribute in your example, so you should replace the last part there by:

```
<h:commandButton value="Register" style="color:red" action="#{Registration.response()}" />
```

And of course, you should also omit the last `<h:outputText />` tag in the `index.xhtml`.

Finally, create the new page `result.xhtml` to show registration informations:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
    <title>Registration informations</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Your registration informations :</h2>

    <h:outputText value="Last name : #{Registration.lastName }" /><br />
    <h:outputText value="First name : #{Registration.firstName }" /><br />
    <h:outputText value="MI : #{Registration.mi}" /><br />
    ...

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For learning purposes, I would post two implementations of the `response` method: one that simply returns `"result"` and another that returns `"result?faces-redirect=true"` and explain the differences between both or point to a link where this is covered and explained. Apart of that, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try change:

```
@javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped
```

to

```
@RequestScoped
```

For more you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928365/jsf-request-scoped-bean-population-problem) @BalusC answer.

Comment: He has both of them imported, but he's only actually *using* the Faces annotations (`ManagedBean` and `RequestScoped`) so he *should* be OK, here, I think.  That said, it's probably best not to import them both, and remove the possible ambiguity.